# display DB connection on site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Just wondering if anyone knows how to display the status of a DB connection on a page.

I would like to know if there is a good connection, or if it is down. In this case I would also display the reason.

Comment: Is there a persistent db connection in your solution? There shouldn't be any. The business layer tries to access the db, if it is successfully it passes the results to the page, otherways it passes the exceptions to the pages. In any case the connection will be closed far before the page is displayed client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with database with asp.net, you  connection shouldn't be open all the time. Keeping in this mind you dont have to (and shouldnt) display connection status of database all the time. What you should do is while performing queries with ado.net or another OR/M just capture [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx)s and provide meaningfull errors to your user.

From msdn article :

```
try {
   // code here
}
catch (SqlException odbcEx) {
   // Handle more specific SqlException exception here.
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   // Handle generic ones here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the db exception, cause it will fire an exception/error once there is no connection.

and if there is a connection, you would know

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it is not really a good practice to tell users about database. Any database error should be logged and replaced with a more user friendly error message.

If you still need to display connection state on the screen, you can handle the StateChange event for SQLConnection and display appropriate message.

Update: I would suggest that you just log the errors and have a program to send you emails with failures or manually look into the system rather than users telling you that your database is down.

Comment: this is ideally what i would like to do, just let them know if the DB is unreachable, and why so they can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways to check for connection status, You may use ASP.Net Timer to periodically check for the connection, ([remember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx) that each timer interval causes a postback to the server and causes network traffic ), See [Walkthrough: Using the ASP.NET Timer Control with Multiple UpdatePanel Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx)

In the `Timer_Tick` event, you may check for the connection and post a message in label. Something on the following lines...

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
       {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn =
            new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                Label1.Text = "Database Available";


            }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
                Label1.Text = "Database Un-Available, " + "Possible Reason:"+ ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Its not a good practice to catch generic exception (`Exception`) , you may catch SQLException and then have another block to handle generic exception.